# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL? why am getting this exception

Tags: java, url

i have a method to send sms to bulk members
here is my java method

```
public void sendSMS(String mobilno,String msg)
{
    URLConnection myURLConnection=null;
    URL myURL=null;
    BufferedReader reader=null;
    String mainUrl="http://smsstreet.in/websms/sendsms.aspx?userid=id&password=pwd&sender=sender&mobileno="+mobilno+"&msg="+msg;
    StringBuilder sbPostData= new StringBuilder(mainUrl);
    mainUrl = sbPostData.toString();  
    try
    {

        myURL = new URL(mainUrl);
        myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
        myURLConnection.connect();
        reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        String response;
        while ((response = reader.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(response);
        reader.close();
    }  
    catch (IOException e)
    {                                
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here is my servlrt:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String mobilnmbers=request.getParameter("mobName");
    System.out.println(mobilnmbers);
    String message=request.getParameter("comment");
    System.out.println(message);  
    SMSMethod sms=new SMSMethod();
    sms.sendSMS(mobilnmbers, message);
}
```

when i call it into servlet its giving following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://smsstreet.in/websms/sendsms.aspx?userid=id&password=pwd&sender=sender&mobileno=9014780300,8309518663,9920221173,9849133273,9849656287,7013083104,8759197399,1234567890,8096613756,7075472796,8121104305,9182176200,9949327590,8309490418,9949913331,8125206381,9550371787,9502167674,9912193234,9912193234,9700237487,9246563935&msg=Have you started booking the train tickets
```

i am new to this smsGatway can anyone help me?

Comment: whats the solution for it?

Comment: Try to get rid of the space blank in your `msg` it may causes your URL to be malformed.

Comment: I am suspecting your url. did you check with postman or something like it client to access the service ?

Comment: if i remove blank spaces message would not it be unreadable @ Asew

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add:
    String mainUrl = mainUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

After this line:
    String mainUrl="http://smsstreet.in/..."

Comment: will %20 this create space?

Comment: thank you very much @Lord Tesla

Comment: At least use a proper escaping function instead of trying to do it yourself. -1

Comment: Yes by replacing  %20 instead of white spaces which is also the same way of saying white space in domain names you will probably solve the problem.